# Kafka- How to get the current ACLs details from the kafka cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I want to get all the Kafka Cluster ACLs details that we've added in until now so I can store them in a data warehouse for reporting purposes.

What is the best way to do that?

The required ACL details are:

```
User, Topic, PermissionType(Write/read), Consumer
```

Answer (score 2):

`kafka-acls` command get you all the details

eg:

```
kafka-acls --bootstrap-server ${broker}:9092 --list
```